# Will not allow me to count values in dictionary for a specific output

Tags: python

Please see code below, the answer keeps outputting 0, please can you see where i have gone wrong

```
statuses = {
    "Alice": "online", 
    "Bob": "online", 
    "Eve": "offline",

}

def online_count(status):
  y = 0
    for i in status.values():
    if status.values() == "online":
      y += 1
      print (y)

 print (y)

  online_count(statuses)
```

Comment: Did you inted to check `if i == "online"`?

Comment: @dm2, omg I am stupid, thanks

Comment: With a comprehension: `sum(1 for i in statuses.values() if i == 'online')`

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if i=="online"

anyway. to give you a little hint of how this can be simplified in python, try using:

```
print(sum(map(("online").__eq__, statuses.values())))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
statuses = {
    "Alice": "online",
    "Bob": "online",
    "Eve": "offline",

}


def online_count(status):
    y = 0
    for i in status.values():
        if i == "online":
            y += 1
            print(y)

    print(y)


online_count(statuses)
```